# Visual Studio Code Analysis - CA1804 thrown when variable is being used

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

I'm using VS2015 on Windows 7.

Code analysis rule CA1804 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182278.aspx) states that I am not using a variable and to remove it. However, I am using this variable further down in my code. This is happening across the whole solution in hundreds of places. The code block looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
{
    string soapResult = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        // code here
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        // code here
        bool isValidated = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // throw error
    }

    return isValidated;
}
```

I'm getting this error from Code Analysis:

**Error CA1804  'ValidateUser(string, string)' declares a variable, 'soapResult', of type 'string', which is never used or is only assigned to. Use this variable or remove it.**

Is there something I'm missing here? It's not within an if/else like some of the instances I'm getting this error. But I figured that if it's being used at all this error would not be thrown.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm confused as to how this even compiles. As written, "isValidated" isn't even in scope when you try to return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the analysis message carefully, note the bit I have highlighted:

> Error CA1804 'ValidateUser(string, string)' declares a variable, 'soapResult', of type 'string', which is never used ***or is only assigned to***. Use this variable or remove it.

It is telling you that you only assign a value to it (you actually do that twice including the initialisation to `string.Empty`) but you *never* use the value. So it's effectively a waste of a variable.

What you should be doing is either using the value, for example:

```
soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
if(soapResult.Contains("something")
{
    isValidated = true;
}
else
{
    //Not needed but added it to better show how this works in context
    isValidated = false;
}
```

Or remove it altogether and discard the result you get from the `StreamReader`:

```
rd.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: The "if" statement is unnecessary here. "isValidated" is true exactly when "soapResults.Contains("something") is true and is false exactly when that statement is false - you can just do a direct assignment. With that said, though, this is definitely the correct answer - the variable is assigned to but never used.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I know that, it's just example code to show what I'm explaining.

Comment: Fair enough, just pointing that out. Your answer's good by the way, I upvoted.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I added a comment to explain it a bit better, thanks

Comment: @DavidG Thanks very much! I understand the issue now. I've marked your answer as correct, I guess I just needed to read it more clearly.